# Null polynomial of $f+g$ and $f \circ g$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

I am stuck on the following problem : let $V$ be a real vector space, not necessarily finite-dimensional and let $\mathrm{End}(V)$ be the space of endomorphisms of $V$. For $u \in \mathrm{End}(V)$, let $N(u)$ be the set of null polynomials of $u$ :
$$ N(u) = \lbrace P \in \mathbb{R}[X], \; P(u) = 0 \rbrace. $$
The problem is stated as follows :

> Let $f,g \in \mathrm{End}(V)$  such that $f \circ g = g \circ f$, $N(f) \neq \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ and $N(g) \neq \lbrace 0 \rbrace$.
>
> Show that $N(f+g) \neq \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ and $N(f \circ g) \neq \lbrace 0 \rbrace$.

Given that $f \circ g = g \circ f$, we can compute powers of $f+g$ using the Binomial theorem. I think this must help somewhere but I do not have many ideas regarding this problem. A naive idea would be to consider a polynomial $S = \sum_{k=0}^{N} a_k X^k \in \mathbb{R}[X]$, compute $S(f+g)$ using the Binomial theorem, and try to determine the coefficients $(a_0,\ldots,a_N)$ with some conditions. However, this idea does not get me far.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{R}[f]$ and $\mathbb{R}[g]$ are finite-dimensional commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebras. Since $f$ and $g$ commute, $\mathbb{R}[f,g]$ is also a finite-dimensional commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra. If $\mathbb{R}[f]$ has basis $1, f, \dotsc, f^a$, and $\mathbb{R}[g]$ has basis $1, g, \dotsc , g^b$, then $\mathbb{R}[f,g]$ is generated (as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space) by $\{ f^{\alpha}\circ g^{\beta} : 0 \leqslant \alpha \leqslant a, \, 0 \leqslant \beta \leqslant b\}$ (this spanning set is in general not linearly independent). Hence the powers of $f+g$ resp. $f\circ g$ cannot be linearly independent, that is, $f + g$ and $f\circ g$ satisfy some polynomial relations.